# How to compact and optimize open policy agent, in a single rego policy

Tags: performance, optimization, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm new to [rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/) and [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) (*Open Policy Agent*) in general.

I'm trying to create a **default** policy for implementations that allow for policy overrides but in normal cases use *"Policy Configuration"* in a simple *JSON* document.

I use the input as the *"Policy Configuration"* and the data is the data that is to be processed by the policy. The data itself is pre-processed where *"$error"* is *JSON* elements that has been evaluated with an error.

The policy seems to work ok, but as I understand it, it must be a much easier way of expressing the same thing in `rego` and hence also much more **optimized** (current policy is taking around 1ms to evaluate).

The [playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/KBrzaYmZl8) contains the below setup to be evaluated on-line.

Cheers,
Mario :)

input.json

```json
{
  "range": {"IDT**": [-100, 100], "RHCS**": [20, 200]},
  "report": ["ODT", "IDT_*_O2"],
  "skip": ["IDT**"]
}
```

data.json

```json
{
  "target": {
    "IDT": 22,
    "IDT_C1_O1": 22.2,
    "IDT_C1_O2": 101,
    "IDT_C1_O3": "$error",
    "IDT_C1_O4": "$error",
    "ODT": "$error",
    "RHCS_C13_O44": "$error"
  }
}
```

and the output after evaluating the *cbprovider* `rego` policy is

```json
{
    "all_errors": [ "RHCS_C13_O44", "IDT_C1_O3", "IDT_C1_O4", "ODT", "IDT_C1_O2" ],
    "report": [ "ODT", "IDT_C1_O2" ],
    "skip": [ "IDT_C1_O3", "IDT_C1_O4" ]
}
```

```rego
package cbprovider

# Errors to be skipped
# If present in report as well it will not be skipped
# (report overrides skip)
skip[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my == "$error"   
    
    matchSkip(dp)
    
    not matchReport(dp)
}

# Errors to be skipped when out of range
skip[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my != "$error"   
    
    matchSkip(dp)
    
    not matchReport(dp)
    
    range := get_range(dp)
    not in_range(my, range[0], range[1])    
}


# Errors to be reported
# If matches both in skip and report -> report overrides skip
report[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my == "$error"   
    
    matchReport(dp)
}

# Errors to be reported when out of range
report[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my != "$error"   
    
    matchReport(dp)

    range := get_range(dp)
    not in_range(my, range[0], range[1])
}


all_errors[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my == "$error"     
}

all_errors[dp] {
    my := data.target[dp]
    my != "$error"
    
    range := get_range(dp)
    not in_range(my, range[0], range[1])
}

in_range(num, low, high) {
    num >= low
    num <= high
}

get_range(dp) = range {
    some key
    range := input.range[key]
    
    glob.match(key, ["_"], dp)
}

matchSkip(dp) {
    some i
    input.skip[i]
    glob.match(input.skip[i], ["_"], dp)
}

matchReport(dp) {
    some i
    input.report[i]
    glob.match(input.report[i], ["_"], dp)
}
```

Comment: I am also testing out OPA, I have a policy created and it works fine and I get desired output when I run it in playground, but I am not sure how do I make the same request through postman, when running OPA as a server, any idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your policy looks fine. If you need to tune it further for performance, I'd suggest looking into shaping your data so that your policy does not need to rely on `glob.match`. From casual testing it looks like that's where about half the evaluation time is currently spent.

Comment: Thanks devoops :) I'll have a check and see if e.g. regex is faster since I need some form of wildcards to make it "workable".